# Elm: match lists of length != n

Tags: elm

I have a testcase where I pass a list of length 3 into a `case`. Since Elm doesn't allow you to miss a case, I need to cover the other cases (and just return `Expect.fail "this should never happen"`).

Listing the cases for a list of length `0, 1, 2, ... n-1` and then `n+1 :: _` works, but it's very verbose.

How do I match a list of any length other than 3? (What if 3 was 477 instead?)

Comment: Do you really need a `case` or would an `if` be good enough?

Comment: @AntoineSnyers I guess an `if` would work as well. It's a `Just [1,2,3]` that I'm matching against.

Answer (score 4):

You only need to match the case of three items and handle every other combination with `_`. Here's an example that turns a list of three into a tuple of size three, or returns `Nothing` when the list isn't exactly three items long.

```elm
toTuple3 : List a -> Maybe (a, a, a)
toTuple3 list =
    case list of
        a :: b :: c :: [] ->
            Just (a, b, c)
        _ ->
            Nothing
```